# Iphone cocas2d game : Playing sound

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

i am also facing same problem .. by doing this background music stop but i my case i want to play another sound for a while .. like a blast sound and then again play old sound .. but whn i do this type of code
     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"blast.wav" loop:TRUE];
     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"background.wav" loop:TRUE];
i blast sound not play ...background sound just stop for a sec .. and thn playing again .. need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
```

After Stopping background music.you can use playEffect.

```
 [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"blast.wav"];
```